# Can a person other than the author start a bounty for a question they like?

Tags: discussion, bounty

Suppose Jack is new to MO and he posts a good question. Tim has a lot of reputations in MO and thinks the question deserves more attentions. Why not we allow Tim to offer some of his reputations to start a bounty for Jack's question?

Once a question is posted, we assume that the author wants the question to receive more attentions and good answers. If other people are curious about the answer, in fact the question belongs to them as well.

Comment: Why did you think it was impossible? I actually did it several times.

Comment: It was not possible in the old version of MO.

Answer (score 17):

Anyone can start a bounty on any question asked by any user.
The question has to be at least two days old and the user awarding the bounty has to have at least 75 reputation.
See [this page](https://mathoverflow.net/help/privileges/set-bounties) for details about bounties.

Answer (score 6):

Not only is it possible to put a bounty on another's question, it's encouraged: you earn the "Investor" badge for the "First bounty you offered on another person's question", and also the "Altruist" badge for the "First bounty you manually awarded on another person's question".  (See [the MO Badges page](https://mathoverflow.net/help/badges). These badges are both new to MO 2.0, I think.  I see that they're also noted on the page that **Joonas Ilmavirta** linked to in his Jan.6 answer.)