# Question eligible for bounty

Tags: support, bounty

many days ago I made this question
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/195492/linearized-action-of-a-torus-and-orbits-in-alexeevs-construction
I didn't receive any answer and I would like to start a bounty to increase the visibility of the question, but I can't find the appropriate button.

So, why isn't there the button "start a bounty"?

Is it because of my few reputation points? They are anyway more than 50, the minimum number of points for the bounty, so I don't think this is the reason..

Is it because my question didn't receive enough points?

If not, why? What should I do?

Thank you very much

Comment: See this question: http://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/2076/55893 You need 75 reputation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The site requires you to have at least 75 reputation points to have the privilege to set a bounty on a question.  The button probably only appears then.

You can find the list of privileges [here](https://mathoverflow.net/help/privileges).